# Would a transparent iris serve its purpose?

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy, eyes

The function of the iris is to regulate the aperture of the pupil. How does the iris obstruct light? Is it due to the pigment present in it? Or is it just due to the sheer presence of it?

I am doing a project where I need to maintain a constant light intensity for albino rats. I was suggested to administer a mydriatic topically but when their iris is transparent, does dilating their pupil make sense?

How is it in human albinos? Does pupil dilation and constriction make a difference in them?

Comment: Human albino Iris is not transparent. Translucent maybe. Administering mydriatics might be at least slightly better than relying on their transparency.

Comment: What did you do in the end? Feel free to self-answer, if you have one?